# Hibernate Criteria API results not matching HQL results for left join fetch

Tags: hibernate, criteria, left-join, criteria-api

I have 2 simple models:

```
class Parent {
   Long id; //auto generated sequence and primary key
   String name;
   Set<Child> children;
}

class Child {
  String name;
  Long parent_id; //foreign key
}
```

I have a hql query like this:

```
FROM Parent p
  left join fetch p.children as children
WHERE p.name = 'John'
```

'children' is a collection (set) of 'Child' model in Parent model.

If 'John' has 2 children,  result of above query gives me list of 2 Parents (same reference) each with 2 children by executing a single query.

I am trying to achieve the same via Criteria API like below:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
c.setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.JOIN);
c.createCriteria("children", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));
c.scroll();
```

With above code, I get the list of 2 parent instances (same reference) with only 1 child element (instead of expected 2) bu executing a single sql query.

What am I doing wrong in api?  When I see the generated sql, it is same.

Comment: It seems like this has something to do with `c.scroll()` and `c.list()` rather than difference between HQL and Criteria API. When I posted the question, I used `query.list()` for HQL and `c.scroll()` for Criteria API. Now I tried all 4 combinations and found out that only c.scroll() is behaving in unexpected manner. I don't understand why or how to fix it.

Comment: It seems like during `scroll`, `session` is looking at only parent identifier in cache, and not updating it with new child associations. But `list` seems to be updating the cached parent object with new child associations. My reasoning is that, it does not want to give 2 different states for same object and hence does not update cached object if it comes across it again during further scrolling. Am I right? I tried `c.setCacheable(false)`/`c.setCacheable(true); c.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE/REFRESH)` but to no effect.

Comment: It looks like I need to scroll ordered parent list and ordered child list with 2 queries and them merge them programmatic-ally outside hibernate. I am wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after debugging through the Hibernate code I think it's a Hibernate bug rather than anything you're doing wrong.

It was fixed in [this Hibernate issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1283), but our Criteria was still returning incomplete child collections in scrollable results. I found that in the `Loader` class there's some logic that decides whether to use the `FetchingScrollableResultsImpl` to handle the rows properly, and on `CriteriaLoader` it never does because `needsFetchingScroll()` always returns false. However `QueryLoader` does use it when a join fetch is used, which is why converting our Criteria into HQL fixed the issue for us.

I intend to file a bug with Hibernate to implement `CriteriaLoader.needsFetchingScroll()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, and here is the code that is equivalent (at least in my situation):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
c.setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.JOIN);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));

List<Parent> list = c.list();
Iterator<Parent> iter = list.iterator();
```

I have the impression that the line
`c.scroll();`  forces a similar behavior to `c.setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY );`

Comment: Actually, that's not what I observed. `c.list()` was returning one parent instance in the list with 2 children if the `DISTRINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` transformer was applied. `c.scroll()` was not affected by this result transformer at all.

Comment: Also, I see that your code does not specify a left join and I am guessing natural join is selected by hibernate by default.

Comment: given a one-to-many relationshit, a left outer join is the default behavior that I observe when I set `FetchMode.JOIN`